# What is a deploy user in Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano

I'm trying to get my head around Capistrano.

What is an ssh deploy user? I've got shared hosting space with ssh access and I usually do ssh myuser@domain.com and it authenticates with private RSA keys.

This is the output I get trying to do a deploy

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO [ee6098c8] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/tempdirname/ as myuser@serveripaddress
DEBUG [ee6098c8] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/tempdirname/
DEBUG [ee6098c8]    stdin: is not a tty
INFO [ee6098c8] Finished in 0.942 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/tempdirname/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/tempdirname/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [f4f1f009] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/tempdirname/git-ssh.sh as myuser@serveripaddress
DEBUG [f4f1f009] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/tempdirname/git-ssh.sh
DEBUG [f4f1f009]    stdin: is not a tty
INFO [f4f1f009] Finished in 0.164 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
INFO [3788f5f2] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.blah/tempdirname-static.git as myuser@serveripaddress
DEBUG [3788f5f2] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/tempdirname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.blah/tempdirname-static.git )
DEBUG [3788f5f2]    stdin: is not a tty
DEBUG [3788f5f2]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [3788f5f2]    git
DEBUG [3788f5f2]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [3788f5f2]    
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as myuser@serveripaddress: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: stdin: is not a tty
/usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: stdin: is not a tty
/usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:11:in `git'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:21:in `check'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/User1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as myuser@serveripaddress: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: stdin: is not a tty
/usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

This is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.3.5
lock "3.4.0" # change the version to the capistrano version you are using - I used capistrano version 3.3.5

set :application, "name"
#set :deploy_user, "your-ssh-deploy-user"
set :deploy_user, "user"

# setup repo details
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git"
set :scm, :git

# how many old releases do we want to keep, not much
set :keep_releases, 2
```

this is my production.rb

```
set :stage, :production # or :staging or :your_environment
set :branch, "master" # or another branch, for example "development"

# used in case we're deploying multiple versions of the same
# app side by side. Also provides quick sanity checks when looking
# at filepaths
set :full_app_name, "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"

#server 'your-ip-address', user: 'your-ssh-deploy-user', roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true
server 'ipaddress', user: 'myuser', roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true

set :deploy_to, "/home/dir/blah/blah"

# whether we're using ssl or not, used for building nginx
# config file
set :enable_ssl, false

#role :app, %w{deploy@your-ip-address}
#role :web, %w{deploy@your-ip-address}
#role :db,  %w{deploy@your-ip-address}
role :app, %w{myuser@myipaddress}
role :web, %w{myuser@myipaddress}
role :db,  %w{myuser@myipaddress}
```

I followed this
http://www.frick-web.at/blog/capistrano-deployment-setup-for-php-projects

Answer (score 0):

Deploy user is  just capistrano vernicular to denote the users that apply to different context such as production, staging servers or different servers in general. I was getting caught up with semantics.